# CSS Carousel using z-index

Tags: css, loops, z-index, carousel

I was wondering if it would be possible, using CSS alone, to create a carousel by switching the z-index of divs at specified intervals (let's say 5 seconds). The divs would be layered on top of each other, and then, as their z-index changed they'd move forward or backward as appropriate, using their div IDs, leaving only one viewable at a time. This process would then loop. Is this possible, and if so, how would I go about doing it? Thanks!

Comment: have a google for css3 animations, it may point you in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSSWizardy created a nice css-only-carousel with changing the left-value.

http://csswizardry.com/2011/10/fully-fluid-responsive-css-carousel/
Not changing the z-index, but should do the magic for you.

Also I just found the solution for you!
Check out this website http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/
Demo 3!